# Why does saliva clean so well?

Tags: cleaning

I notice that saliva seems to clean well, much better than plain water. For example, tar spots on the car can be difficult to get off. I typically use really powerful solvents to get them off, like 95% acetone and things like that. Yet, saliva works too.

Why is this?

Comment: Saliva has proteins which act like mild surfactants (detergent effect) and of course mechanical abrasion helps to physically dislodge the spots.

Answer (score 6):

Saliva has [alpha-amylase (ptyalin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-amylase), which hydrolyzes carbohydrates (so starch starts to taste sweet in just a few seconds), [kallikrein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kallikrein), an enzyme that breaks down protein, and [lingual lipase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingual_lipase), which helps disintegrates fats (lipids).

So next time you clean off a splattered insect from your wind-screen (windshield, should you prefer), think of it as [external digestion, as practiced by flies](https://asknature.org/strategy/food-digested-externally/) and [by starfish](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/08/130801233100.htm). Or perhaps you might *not* want to consider that thought...